# Working with std::function on C libraries

Tags: c++, c, function, c++11, callback

I have a C library function with the following signature,

```
void register_callback(void (*callback)(int, void*), void* args);
```

What is the best way to get this to work with, if I have a callback of the form,

```
std::function<void(int)>?
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938774/get-function-pointer-from-stdfunction-when-using-stdbind) helps.

Comment: I assume that `void* args` is for userdata, that you can cast back to your type.

Comment: Is your register callback **actually** `void register_callback(void(*callback)(void*,int), void* args)` by any chance?  If yes, please correct.  If no, please provide more information on how the callback works, and what the arguments mean.  Ideally actually copy-paste the actual callback interface here, don't paraphrase.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it is for userdata

Comment: Avoid std:::function (If you bind to a class, have a static function dispatching to a member-function, where `args` represents the class object)

Comment: @Yakk you are right. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::function<void(int)> bob;
register_callback( [](int x, void* pbob){
  auto& bob = *static_cast<std::function<void(int)>*>(pbob);
  bob(x);
}, &bob );
```

this remains valid for as long as the variable `bob` does.

A copy of `bob` is not enough, the actual instance of `bob` that we took a pointer to in the `register_callback` call has to live long enough.

If this is difficult, consider a smart pointer wrapping said `std::function` and doing a pointer to the stored `std::function`.

There will be modest overhead in the above, in that we dispatch over a function pointer, then over the equivalent of a vtable, then inside the `std::function` again.

What is going on above is that I make a stateless lambda to convert the `void* args` into a pointer-to-`std::function`, and invoke that `std::function` with the `int`.  Stateless lambdas can convert to function pointers implicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a little more on your suggestion of using smart pointer? Did you mean to create a std::function object on heap and wrap it with a smart pointer? But then I would have to ensure that the the smart pointer remains valid right?

Comment: @vikky.rk Yes but copies of the smart pointer mean that the pointer-to-element remain valid; unlike copies of the `std::function`.  So a bit easier to deal with.

Comment: Makes sense. One more question: Where is the lambda stored when it get converted to function pointer?

Comment: @vikky.rk It isn't.  There is no state to store.  Well, the 1 byte no-state could be stored somewhere while it is a function, but neither calling the lambda nor the function *use* that state in any real sense.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
class CallBack
{
public:
    explicit CallBack(std::function<void(int)> f) : f(f) {}

    static void to_c_api(int a, void* that)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<CallBack*>(that)->f(a);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(int)> f;
};
```

You may then do

```
CallBack callback; // should live longer than the calls
void register_callback(CallBack::to_c_api, &callback);
```