# Compiler error wrapping an interpretable function

Tags: c++

I have a legacy C code base, which I am migrating to C++ in a piecemeal fashion. It includes an interpreter, so there is a need to wrap static functions and arguments for use by the interpreter. So a typical function for export to the interpreter may have the following signature:

`static void do_strstr(struct value * p)`

and be exposed to the interpreter like so:

```
using vptr = void (*) ();
template <typename Func>
constexpr vptr to_vptr(Func && func)
{ return reinterpret_cast<vptr>(func); }


struct function string_funs[] = {
     ...
        { C_FN3,        X_A3,   "SSI",  to_vptr(do_strstr),     "find" },
    ...
    };
```

This has been proven to work. The drawback with the method so far is that the called function must allocate memory onto a temporary stack. An improvement would be where the called function just returns a string, for example. This function is then wrapped, where the wrapper does the memory magic behind the scenes. This allows functions to created in a more vanilla way.

Here is an implementation which concatenates two strings using my improved method:

```
static std::string do_concata(struct value* p)
{
        std::string s1 = (p)->gString();
        std::string s2 = (p+1)->gString();
        return s1+s2;
}
```

I create a helper function:

```
static void do_concata_1(struct value* p)
{
        wrapfunc(do_concata)(p);
}
```

where the somewhat generic wrapper is defined as:

```
std::function<void(struct value*)>
wrapfunc(std::function<std::string(struct value*)> func)
{
        auto fn = [=](struct value* p) { 
                std::string s = func(p);
                char* ret = alloc_tmp_mem(s.size()+1);          
                strcpy(ret,  s.c_str());
                p->sString(ret);
                return; 
        };
        return fn;
}
```

which is exposed to the interpreter as follows:

```
struct function string_funs[] = {
...
{ C_FN2,        X_A2,   "SS",    to_vptr(do_concata_1),    "concata" },
...

};
```

I am not satisfied with this solution, though, as it requires a helper function for each function I define. It would be better if I could eliminate `do_concata_1` and write another function that wraps the `wrapfunc`.

And this is where the problem is. If I write:

```
vptr to_vptr_1(std::function<void(struct value*)> func)
{
        return to_vptr(wrapfunc(func));
}
```

then the compiler complains:

```
stringo.cc: In function ‘void (* to_vptr_1(std::function<void(value*)>))()’:
stringo.cc:373:30: error: could not convert ‘func’ from ‘std::function<void(value*)>’ to ‘std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(value*)>’
  return to_vptr(wrapfunc(func));
```

which is bizarre in my mind, because where did the `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` come from? It should be `void`, surely?

I'm at a loss to see what the fix should be. I am also a bit confused as to whether I should be passing copies of functions, references to functions, or the enigmatic `&&` r-vale references.

Comment: The only realistic fix here is to burn the whole thing with fire, and reimplement it, from scratch, in type-safe form using modern C++.

Comment: @Sam. The codebase is hairy, that's true, but I'd rather refactor than rewrite. Remember, too, that because the functions are being used in an interpreter, there has to be a mechanism for wrapping and unwrapping functions anyway. The whole alloc_tmp_mem() and strcpy() is unfortunate, but not a disaster. At least with my proposed refactoring a pinch-point is created in the code. This will allow me to improve the code at a single point later date.

Answer (score 0):

In `to_vptr_1()`, `func` is established as a function that returns `void`.  But `func` is passed to `wrapfunc()`, which expects a function that returns `std::string`.  The compiler does not have a way to convert `func` from `std::function<void(struct value*)>` to `std::function<std::string(struct value*)>`, so it emits the error message.

`reinterpret_cast` from `std::function` to raw function pointer is not going to work.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938774/get-function-pointer-from-stdfunction-when-using-stdbind) has some good discussion on the topic, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530465/working-with-stdfunction-on-c-libraries?noredirect=1&lq=1) has a solution that could perhaps be reworked for this situation.