# Pass a function of n arguments as function of n-x arguments

Tags: c++, function, c++11, currying, reduction

This is a very basic question and I'm sure this was answered before, but I don't know what to search for.

Stated I have a function that integrates a mathematical function:

```
double integrator(double (*func_to_integrate)(double,double));
```

But my function to integrate is of a type that allows me to manipulate more than two parameters, for example:

```
double func_to_integrate(double mu, double w0, double x, double y);
```

So that I can loop over different values of mu and w0 and compare the results of integration.
How can I pass a function like func_to_integrate to integrator?

Greetings

Edit: As alain pointed out in the comments this is partly a duplicate of: [How can currying be done in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152005/how-can-currying-be-done-in-c)

Is there an elegant solution doing a currying operation on a function pointer?

Comment: When `integrator` calls `func_to_integrate`, what should the values of `mu` and `w0` be? You might want to look into [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: They should be some doubles I can manipulate in a loop. I tried lambda functions and bind. For both I wasn't able to create an object that integrator would accept.

Comment: Why your function and integrator do not return `double`?

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: You'll have to change the signature of `integrator`. With its current signature, the only thing you can do is make `mu` and `w0` globals instead of additional parameters.

Comment: How do you "have" `integrator`? Do you have source?

Comment: What you want to do is called "Currying". It's discussed in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152005/how-can-currying-be-done-in-c), however I'm not sure if it works with function pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Seems it's only possible using <functional>.

Comment: I thought it was not a duplicate because you use a function pointer ;-) I voted to close it as duplicate now.

Comment: I edited the question maybe there's a clever solution for function pointers.

Comment: Ok I retracted my close vote now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are able to change the signature of the `integrator` function, there are several solutions. The basic two directions are

1. use a general template parameter instead of the function pointer (--where the caller has to be aware of the correct signature to pass), or
2. use `std::function<double(double, double)>` as the function argument.

Both alternatives allow you to pass general function objects (functors, lambdas, a `std::bind`-object, etc.). I'd go with alternative 1. as it usually gives a better performance.

Then you can easily set up a lambda:

```
double mu = 1.0;
double w0 = 1.0;
auto f = [mu, w0] (double x, double y) { return func_to_integrate(mu, w0, x, y); };
```

and pass f to your (adusted) `integrator` routine.

---

Here is further an alternative if you cannot change the function signature -- as it is often the case for third-party libraries.

I first thought there is no solution in this case, as you can't bind a general functor to a function pointer. But then I encountered the nice idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422878/2412846) (which I slightly adjusted): encode everything in terms of a static `std::function` variable, then use a static function to call this `std::function` object. As the static function is just syntactic sugar for a global function, it is possible to set up a function pointer to it:

```
template <typename Res, typename... Args>
struct function_ptr_helper
{
public:
    template<typename function_type>
    static auto bind(function_type&& f) { func = std::forward<function_type>(f); }

    static auto invoke(Args... args) { return func(args...); }
    static auto* ptr() { return &invoke; }

private:
    static std::function<Res(Args ...)> func;
};

template <typename Res, typename... Args>
std::function<Res(Args ...)> function_ptr_helper<Res, Args...>::func;

template <typename Res, typename ... Args>
auto* get_function_ptr(std::function<Res(Args...)> f)
{
    using type = function_ptr_helper<Res, Args...>;

    type::bind(std::move(f));
    return type::ptr();
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/RfLTr6)

You can use it as

```
double mu = 1.0;
double w0 = 1.0;
std::function<double(double, double)> f
    = [mu, w0] (double x, double y) { return func_to_integrate(mu, w0, x, y); };

integrator(get_function_ptr(f));
```

Be aware, however, that you are dealing with global variables here. This often works, but sometimes might lead to subtle errors (for example when you call `get_function_ptr` more than once in a single expression).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass a function like func_to_integrate to integrator?

Seems very easy to fix. Just add two more arguments to your pointer function signature.

```
double integrator(double (*func_to_integrate)(double,double,double,double));
```

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments point out the most elegant solution would be using bind and or lambda.  A nice solution would be an adapter design pattern class wrapper, where mu and w0 become class members.

```
class IntegratorAdaptor {
  private:
    double _mu, double _w0;

  public:
    IntegratorAdapter(double arg_mu, double arg_w0)
    : _mu(arg_mu), _w0(arg_w0) { }

    double twoArgIntegrator( double x, double y )
      { return func_to_intergrate( _mu, _w0, x, y ); }
};
```

Construction of this class is very low overhead, so I made the members immutable.  I didn't come up with very good names for the class and functions, you should put more thought into those names than I did.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers I've seen for this kind of question rely on `std::function` and/or C++ templates.  I wanted to share an alternate solution which may be less general, but to me is simpler.  **It doesn't use `std::function` or templates---in fact, it doesn't use any libraries at all.**

The idea is that instead of passing around a function pointer, you pass around an object that implements a particular 'interface'.  In this example,

```
double integrator(double (*func_to_integrate)(double,double))
```

becomes

```
double integrator(Integratable func_to_integrate)
```

where `Integratable` is an 'interface' (abstract base class) defined as

```
class Integratable {
public:    
    virtual double compute(double x, double y) = 0;  // pure virtual function
}
```

We can then make `func_to_integrate` into an instance of this class, with extra members for the additional parameters:

```
class SomeClassName : public Integratable {
public:
    double compute(double x, double y);
    double mu;
    double w0;
}

SomeClassName func_to_integrate;
```

To test several values of `mu` and `w0` in a loop:

```
for(double mu : mus) {
    for(double w0 : w0s) {
        func_to_integrate.mu = mu;
        func_to_integrate.w0 = w0;
        integrator(func_to_integrate);
    }
}
```

Of course, we have to modify `integrator` so that instead of calling a function pointer, it calls the `compute()` method on the object passed to it, but this is trivial (assuming you can change the signature of `integrator`, which is probably required for any possible solution to this problem).

I like this solution because it avoids some of C++'s more heavyweight features and libraries.  However, it certainly is less general than many of the other solutions that are often suggested for partial application in C++.  For OP I believe this solution is an elegant fit for the given use case.