# How can a function that requires another function as a parameter can be used within a class in c++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, std-function, static-cast

I have seen this question in different flavors but it does not really address my issue. Here is the situation, I want to use a library, but one of the functions is extremely complex and requires a `void(*func)(std::vector<double> &x,double& func,void* ptr)` as an input.

I have a class that holds all the key data members, and naturally the function needed by the external library must be a member function. From my understanding, it is not possible. What are the tricks to bypass that requirement?

Normally, I use `std::function` and `std::bind` but I don't think there is a way to convert an std::function to `void *`, and again I cant change the external library. The use of static function prevents me to have access to key data members.

The signature of the library function is

```c
void minlbfgsoptimize(
    minlbfgsstate &state,
    void (*func)(const real_1d_array &x, double &func, void *ptr),
    void (*rep)(const real_1d_array &x, double func, void *ptr) = NULL,
    void *ptr = NULL);
```

The full code is in https://github.com/hjkuijf/ALGLIB/blob/master/src/optimization.h

Comment: Please try make you question friendly for the reader. This single paragraph discourage fro reading. Split this into multiple paragraphs. You are complaining about third party library but you didn't show how its API looks like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get function pointer from std::function when using std::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938774/get-function-pointer-from-stdfunction-when-using-stdbind)

Comment: You just need a wrapper struct for std::function that you can take a pointer to, and then a helper function that casts the pointer back from void to the wrapper before invoking the contained std::function.

Comment: The 3rd parameter `void* ptr` suggests that you are supposed to call something like `setCallbackData` with a pointer to whatever you want and that pointer will be passed back in callback. In particular, you can pass `this` and access member functions with `reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(ptr)->memberMethod();`

Comment: That is the signature of the third pary library function :

`void minlbfgsoptimize(minlbfgsstate &state,
    void (*func)(const real_1d_array &x, double &func, void *ptr),
    void  (*rep)(const real_1d_array &x, double func, void *ptr) = NULL,
    void *ptr = NULL);`

Comment: The code can be found in https://github.com/hjkuijf/ALGLIB/blob/master/src/optimization.h , line 2425

Comment: Presumably, the last parameter in `minlbfgsoptimize` is the pointer to whatever is passed back to callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a C style callback.  That void ptr is going to be passed some pointer you provide.

Your job is to make that ptr have the state you need.

In your case, it can be a pointer to your class.

```
struct Foo {
  static void callback(std::vector<double> &x,double& f,void* ptr){
    return static_cast<Foo*>(ptr)->callback_impl(x, f);
  }
  void callback_impl(std::vector<double>& x, double&f);
};
```

Now when calling you oass `this` as `ptr`:

```
minlbfgsoptimize(state,Foo::callback, nullptr, this);
```

where `this` is a `Foo*`.

Static member functions are just functions.  And pointers can round-trip through being a `void*` so long as the in and out types match exactly.